# Control over loading elements in multipage web app(Python/Dash)

Tags: python, performance, plotly-dash, multipage

I am building a multipage dashboard in dash/python. It has to conduct a number of SQL queries and pandas operations and it seems like all of that is being processed when I run it, it loads super long on run and then works very super quick once loaded. My question is how can I have control over it? If I want for an instance spread loading time across pages so the initial load isn't so long and then there is a bit of loading when the page is being switched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The long loading issue was solved by implementing a pickle file to store the historical data and by sorting out imports.